# Posicionamento de label e inputs em um formulário html

Tags: html, html5, css3, formulário

Olá, estou estudando HTML5 e CSS3 e estou tentando estilizar realizando o posicionamento dos inputs/checkbox/combobox e suas respectivas labels.

Suponhamos que tenho o seguinte código:

```html
<form>
    <label for="Input1" id="lbl1">Input 1</label>
<input id="Input1" type="text">

<label for="Input2" id="lbl2">Input 2</label>
<input id="Input2" type="text">

<label for="Input3" id="lbl3">Input 3</label>
<input id="Input3" type="text">

<label for="combobox1" id="lbl4">Combobox 1</label>
<select id="combobox1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<label for="combobox2" id="lbl5">Combobox 2</label>
<select id="combobox2">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<label for="Input4" id="lbl5">Input 4</label>
<input id="Input4" type="text">

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="selecionado"> <label for="checkbox" id="lbl6">Checkbox</label>

<label for="Input5"id="lbl7">Input 5</label>
<input id="Input5" type="text">
</form>
```

Como faço para que a pagina fique posiciona nesse estilo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem várias soluções para esse layout. Uma solução passa por visualizar o espaço em três colunas e assim criar três `<div>`, um para cada coluna e por os `<div>` lado a lado com `display` `flex`. Depois é necessário colocar cada um dos elementos que estavam no `<form>` na coluna apropriada.

Exemplo:

```css
form {
  display:flex; /*O form tem os três divs logo é o que fica com o display flex*/
}

.coluna {
  padding:10px; /*cria um espaçamento para dentro nas colunas para não ficarem "coladas"*/
}

.coluna input, .coluna select {
  margin-bottom:20px; /*distanciar as caixas verticalmente dentro dos divs*/
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="coluna"> <!-- aqui a coluna 1 -->
    <label for="Input1" id="lbl1">Input 1</label>
    <input id="Input1" type="text">
    
    <label for="combobox1" id="lbl4">Combobox 1</label>
    <select id="combobox1">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    
    <label for="Input4" id="lbl5">Input 4</label>
    <input id="Input4" type="text">
    
    <label for="Input5"id="lbl7">Input 5</label>
    <input id="Input5" type="text">
  </div>
  
  <div class="coluna"> <!-- aqui a coluna 2 -->
    <label for="Input2" id="lbl2">Input 2</label>
    <input id="Input2" type="text">
    <label for="combobox2" id="lbl5">Combobox 2</label>
    <select id="combobox2">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="selecionado"> <label for="checkbox" id="lbl6">Checkbox</label>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="coluna"> <!-- aqui a coluna 3 -->
    <label for="Input3" id="lbl3">Input 3</label>
    <input id="Input3" type="text">
  </div>
  
</form>
```

Comment: Gostei :) <br> Apenas realizei algumas alterações. Na classe coluna troquei o padding de 10px para 1.5rem, e acrescentei o width: 10% e para finalizar, na coluna última classe troquei o margin-bottom de 20px para .5rem